# Open Veracrypt container (password+keyfile) without password?

Tags: encryption, password-cracking, truecrypt, veracrypt, hashcat

I lost my password for encrypted disk.
Is there a way to do something without dumb cracking?
Maybe recovery mode? Because I just lost 50% of my auth data...?